# model.predict_classes is deprecated - What to use instead?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I have been trying to revisit my python code for prediction on neural network and i realized after running the code that `model.predict_classes` is deprecated since 1st Jan 2021.

Kindly can you support me to know what i can use instead for my code ?

The code line is:

```
y_pred_nn = model.predict_classes(X_test)
```

The issue:

```
NameError
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-fc1ddbecb622> in <module>
----> 1 print(y_pred_nn)

NameError: name 'y_pred_nn' is not defined
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is answered exactly on stack exchange: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/79761/class-label-prediction-in-keras-sequential-model-showing-different-results-in-co

Comment: use `np.argmax(model.predict(x_test), axis=-1)`

Answer (score 18):

The best explanation of how to handle this is given at:

https://androidkt.com/get-class-labels-from-predict-method-in-keras/

First use `model.predict()` to extract the class probabilities.  Then depending on the number of classes do the following:

#### Binary Classification

Use a threshold to select the probabilities that will determine class 0 or 1

```
np.where(y_pred > threshold, 1,0)
```

For example use a threshold of 0.5

#### Mutli-class Classification

Select the class with the highest probability

```
np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
```

#### Multi-label Classification

Where you can have multiple output classes per example, use a threshold to select which labels apply.

```
y_pred = model.predict(x, axis=1)
[i for i,prob in enumerate(y_pred) if prob > 0.5]
```

Answer (score 10):

If your model performs multi-class classification (e.g. if it uses a softmax last-layer activation) use:

```
np.argmax(model.predict(x), axis=-1)
```

If your model performs binary classification (e.g. if it uses a sigmoid last-layer activation) use:

```
(model.predict(X_test) > 0.5).astype("int32")
```

Answer (score 3):

`model.predict_classes` is deprecated, as mentioned by @Kaveh, use `model.predict()` function instead.

```
np.argmax(model.predict(x_test), axis=-1)
```

To know more about `model.predict()` check this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential?version=nightly#predict).

Comment: This only covers the multi-class classification case, see my answer for binary or multi-label classification.

Comment: You should modify your answer since it does not fully cover `binary` or `multi-class` classification! Your answer only fits the **multi-class** classification!

Answer (score 1):

These two lines of code will give you the same as before:

```
predictions = model.predict(X_text)
predicted_classes = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
```

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

`model.predict_classes()` provides the output classes for the parameter.
It has been removed from Keras for some reasons.
Instead, if you use `model.predict()`, you will end up getting output predictions for the input samples. It is mainly used for batch processing of large number of inputs. Though they are not the same thing, you will get an idea what you are aiming for.

Answer (score 0):

`model.predict_classes` can be replaced by the following code snippet

However before that we need to mention the following:

```
ANN_model.fit(X_train,y_train, epochs=150) #Fitting the model
y_ANN_prediction = ANN_model.predict(X_test) #predicting y data from the fitted model
```

This will predict the probability of the input #1  falling to one of the outputs

**For Example:** For Row 1 or Input 1 we can get the following if we requested 3 probability outputs [0.03745461, 0.53267044, 0.42987496]. In other words the this row says that the middle class or [1] is what the input has the highest probability to fall into

---

To get a numpy array that represents the index positon of the highest probabilty you will need to do the following:

```
y_ANN_prediction_classes = []
for x in y_ANN_prediction: 
    y_ANN_prediction_classes.append(np.argmax(x))

#Conver the list back to a numpy arrach
y_ANN_prediction_classes_arr = np.array(y_ANN_prediction_classes)
```

---

```
y_ANN_prediction_classes_arr #-> This will return [1] for [0.03745461, 0.53267044, 0.42987496]. which represents the index of the highest probability
```