# Operators with Conditional Statements Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, if-statement, operators

I followed a facial detection algorithm linked [here](https://data-flair.training/blogs/python-project-driver-drowsiness-detection-system/comment-page-4/#comments).

I found out that the program is pretty outdated, for example, using `model.predict_classes` instead of `model.predict`. After going through multiple StackOverflow and GitHub discussions, I can run the code without any difficulty, but then I encountered an error, `The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()` is the lines

```
if(lpred[0]==1):
    lbl='Open'
if(lpred[0]==0):
    lbl='Closed'
```

I changed this to

```
if lpred.all()==1:
    lbl='Open'
if lpred.all()==0:
    lbl='Closed'
```

I encountered the same problem in line

```
if (rpred[0]==0 and lpred[0]==0):
```

I changed it to

```
if np.logical_and((rpred.all()) == 0, (lpred.all()) == 0):
```

But now the code is not working. I thought this could be because I had initialized `lpred` and `rpred` as python `list`.

```
rpred=[99]
lpred=[99]
```

I changed this to this

```
rpred = np.array(99)
lpred = np.array(99)
```

But this issue remains the same.

```
if np.logical_and((rpred.all()) == 0, (lpred.all()) == 0):
    score=score+1
    cv2.putText(frame,"Closed",(10,height-20), font, 1,(255,255,255),1,cv2.LINE_AA)
    # print(score)
# if(rpred[0]==1 or lpred[0]==1):
else:
    score=score-1
    # print(score)
    cv2.putText(frame,"Open",(10,height-20), font, 1,(255,255,255),1,cv2.LINE_AA)
```

Some debugging helped in determining that the `if` condition is not running and only the `else` condition is executing as the score remains -1 in any case. I am unsure how to solve this.

The whole script can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/SDDr4ei6).

Comment: The arrays returned by .predict and .predict_classes are not of the same dimensions. See a solution [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68776790/model-predict-classes-is-deprecated-what-to-use-instead)

Comment: Oh, I was so not aware. Will take a thorough look at the documentation. Thanks